# Use "not required" in Symfony3 when building forms with FosrestBundle

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm building an API with FosrestBundle and Symfony3. In some part of my work, I've to build forms, and I want some fields of my form set to "not required". But I got errors when I tried creating them.

Here is how I created a form for one of my entity : "Question".

Firstly I created a QuestionType class where I set a required to false:

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('libelle');
    $builder->add('description');
    $builder->add('imageRoot');
    $builder->add('page', 'integer', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('ligne', 'integer', array('required' => false));

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Question',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ]);
}
}
```

Secondly, I configured validation parameters in my validation.yml file :

```
AppBundle\Entity\Question:
properties:
    libelle:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type: string
    description:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Type: string
    imageRoot:
        - Type: string
    page:
        - Type: integer
        - GreaterThan:
            value: 0
        - LessThanOrEqual:
            value: 1000

    ligne:
        - Type: integer
        - GreaterThan:
            value: 0
        - LessThanOrEqual:
            value: 1000
```

Thirdly, I created my form in a controller

```
class ContenuController extends Controller{

/**
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"contenu"}, statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Post("/lectureContenu/{id}/Questions")
 */
public function postQuestionAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $contenu = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contenu')->find($request->get('id'));
    $typeQuestion = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:TypeQuestion')->find(1);

    if (empty($contenu)) {
        return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Contenu de la question inexistant'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    $question = new Question();
    $question->setContenu($contenu)
             ->setTypeQuestion($typeQuestion);

    $form = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
    $form->submit($request->request->all()); // Validation des données

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($question);
        $em->flush();

        return $question;
    } else {
        return $form;
    }

  }
 }
```

Finally, when I run my code with the example below (using Postman) :

```
 {
  "libelle": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "imageRoot": "test"
 }
```

I got this error :

```
...
"message": "Could not load type \"integer\"",
"class": "Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException",
...
```

I don't know why ! For me, everything seems correct. Please help !

Comment: Why do you add `return $options;` in the `buildForm` method of `QuestionType` form???

Comment: It's a mistake, I just remove it :)

Comment: Please, Add the validation constraints of the `AppBundle\Entity\Question` entity and the related code. (es: some custom constraint).

Comment: Please why do I need to add validation constraints ? And for which properties do I need to add it  on Question entity ?

Comment: It seems the lonely dash (4th dash for the page property in your validation.yml) is considered a constraint. Symfony may not instanciate a Constraint from an empty configuration.

Comment: @LexLustor , it was a mistake. I just remove it and I got another error ( I edited my post, you can see it)

Comment: @EdgarKAMDEM This time, the error is about the definition of the fields *page* and *ligne* in your form type : the string integer is not a valid option anymore in SF3, use IntegerType::class instead in your form definition.

Comment: Thx, it works great now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer to remove this question from the unanswered ones.

Types names were **deprecated** in Symfony 2.8 and **removed** in Symfony 3.

When you add child to your form type, you have to use the fully qualified name (FQN) of the type.
You can do it in 2 ways (exemple with your Integer type)

```
$builder->add('page', IntegerType::class)
```

or

```
$builder->add('page', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType');
```

If you use the first option, don't forget to import the class in your class definition:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
```

The list of all types is available here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html